# Low resolution images in a uiscrollview until on-screen or back one / plus one

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `uiscrollview` that I send an array of low res images. When the scrollview scrolls it should check the current page and `+/-1` and replace the low resolution images with high resolution images from another array. My code ALMOST does this flawlessly.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
pageCOntrolBeingUsed = NO;

//calculate the current page that is shown

CGFloat pageWidth = self.uis_valueScrollview.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.uis_valueScrollview.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.uis_valuePageControl.currentPage = page;
    NSLog(@"page %i",page);

    // display the image and +/-1 for smoother scrolling

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.uis_valueScrollview.frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.uis_valueScrollview.frame.size;

        UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [subview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        subview.image = [ebappdelegate.arr_highRezImages objectAtIndex:page];
        subview.tag = page+1;
        [self.uis_valueScrollview addSubview:subview];

     //remove image views except -1 and +1 of the current page

    for ( int i = 0; i < [ebappdelegate.arr_ValueImages count]; i++ ) {
          if ( (i < (page-1) || i > (page+1)) && [uis_valueScrollview viewWithTag:(i+1)] ) {
            [[uis_valueScrollview viewWithTag:(i+1)] removeFromSuperview];
              [[uis_valueScrollview viewWithTag:(i-1)] removeFromSuperview];
             [(UIImageView*)[uis_valueScrollview viewWithTag:page] setImage:[ebappdelegate.arr_lowrezImages objectAtIndex:page]];
            subview.tag = page+1;
            [self.uis_valueScrollview addSubview:subview];
            NSLog(@"remove");
        }
    }

}
```

So right now a function (not here) loads the array of lowrez images beforehand. Upon scrolling I give it access to the highrez array. Once the images scroll off `(+/-1)` I want to replace the higher with the low resolution.

It does this but sometimes creates extra image views (I logged `uiimageview` `iskindofclass` and the number would move up and down, greater than the count of the array so I know extras are being created and not removed.

Any pointers? I think this is a good way to do this and very close - but would take any advice as well.

Comment: Can you show the logging code you use, that you say shows the *problem*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code. you have done the things perfectly.
The increased count that you are finding is due to indicator images.

Each `UIScrollView` class contains horizontal and vertical scroll indicators and shadow. These  members are of type `UIImageView`. Hence while you are logging the `UIImageView` class, it counts these three subviews as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are looking for http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m.html

It is a demo application from apple that does exactly what you are looking for...